# Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors

Tags: java

I am getting an error while saving my flight information into  mysql db.Please help me
Below is my code :

I have tried all the ways by adding pattern and 
so many

It does not convert from String to date

CONSOLE LOG

```
2020-05-12 13:19:21.040[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m5472[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-8][0;39m [36m.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'flight' on field 'dateOfDeparture': rejected value [2020-05-20]; codes [typeMismatch.flight.dateOfDeparture,typeMismatch.dateOfDeparture,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [flight.dateOfDeparture,dateOfDeparture]; arguments []; default message [dateOfDeparture]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'dateOfDeparture'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Date] for value '2020-05-20'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
Field error in object 'flight' on field 'estimatedDepartureTime': rejected value [2020-05-20]; codes [typeMismatch.flight.estimatedDepartureTime,typeMismatch.estimatedDepartureTime,typeMismatch.java.sql.Timestamp,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [flight.estimatedDepartureTime,estimatedDepartureTime]; arguments []; default message [estimatedDepartureTime]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Timestamp' for property 'estimatedDepartureTime'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.sql.Timestamp] for value '2020-05-20'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]]]
```

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reservation?useSSL=false&serverTimeZone=IST&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

server.servlet.context-path=/flight-reservation

spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=*****
spring.mail.password=SunMoon@123
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true

#Defined in logback.xml
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.file.name=D:/backup-Mahesh-Accion/logs/flight-reservation.log

com.accion.reservation.itenery.dirpath=C:/Users/Desktop/reservation/tickets
com.accion.reservation.itenery.email.body=Please find your attached flight booking tickets and Happy Journey! :)
com.accion.reservation.itenery.email.subject=Flight Booking Tickets Mahesh
```

FlightController.java

```
@Controller
public class FlightController {

@Autowired
    private FlightRepository flightRepository;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/saveFlight", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addFlight(@ModelAttribute @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Flight flight ) {
        flightRepository.save(flight);
        return "addFlight";

    }
}
```

flight.java entity class

```
Entity
public class Flight  {
private String flightNumber;

  private int id
    private String operatingAirlines;
    private String departureCity;
    private String arrivalCity;

    private Date dateOfDeparture;
    private Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime;

  //setters and getters
```

FlightRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface FlightRepository extends JpaRepository<Flight, Long> {

}
```

addFlight.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Flight</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Add Flight :</h2>

    <form action="saveFlight"  method="post">

    FlightNumber :<input type="text" name="flightNumber"> </br>
    Airlines Name: <input type="text" name="operatingAirlines"></br>
    Departure City : <input type="text" name="departureCity"></br>
    Arrival City: <input type="text" name="arrivalCity"></br>
    Date Of Departure: <input type="date" name="dateOfDeparture"></br>
    Estimated Date of Departure: <input type="date" name="estimatedDepartureTime"></br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Save Flight"></br>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")` on date type field in `Flight` class.
As you use date data eg: `2020-05-20` for `estimatedDepartureTime` use `Date` type for this.

```
public class Flight  {
    ...
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dateOfDeparture;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date estimatedDepartureTime;
}
```